# why is my square (snake) only moving diagonally?

Tags: python, pygame, keydown, keyup

I am coding 2 snakes/cars and my first snake/car, which use the WASD keyboard format, works perfectly.
 But my second snake/car, which uses the arrow keys, is only moving diagonally.
 I want both snakes/cars to move in every direction (up, down, left, right, AND diagonally) but right now, the second snake/car only moves diagonally.

````py
    #initialize variables for player 1
    car1x = 250
    car1y = 300
    car1width = 20
    car1height = 20
    car1dx = 0
    car1dy = 0
    speed = 3

    #initialize variables for player 2
    car2x = 500
    car2y = 300
    car2width = 20
    car2height = 20
    car2dx = 0
    car2dy = 0
    speed = 3

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # set main loop to True so it will run
    main = True

    # main loop
    while main:
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # check for any events (i.e key press, mouse click etc.)
            if event.type ==pygame.QUIT: # check to see if it was "x" at top right of screen
                main = False         # set the "main" variable to False to exit while loop
            if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    car1dx = 0
                    car1dy = -speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    car1dx = 0
                    car1dy = speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:     
                    car1dx = -speed                     
                    car1dy = 0                          
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    car1dx = speed
                    car1dy = 0


                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    car2dx = 0
                    car2dy = -speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    car2dx = 0
                    car2dy = speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:     
                    car2dx = -speed                     
                    car2dy = 0                          
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    car2dx = speed
                    car2dy = 0

                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key in (pygame.K_w, pygame.K_s):
                    car1dx = 0
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d):
                    car1dy = 0

                if event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
                    car1dx = 0
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    car1dy = 0

# move the x and y positions of the player
            oldcar1x = car1x
            oldcar1y = car1y

            oldcar2x = car2x
            oldcar2y = car2y

            car1x = car1x + car1dx
            car1y = car1y + car1dy

            car2x = car2x + car2dx
            car2y = car2y + car2dx

            if car1x >= screenwidth:
                car1x = oldcar1x
                car1y = oldcar1y

            if car2x >= screenwidth:
                car2x = oldcar2x
                car2y = oldcar2y

          ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because that the key up detection is **an if/elif and if/elif unlike the *key down***. Or maybe it's **because that *you didn't specify the key up detection for the 2nd car***. I dunno, just a suggestion. I can't comment.

---

I can comment now! yay

Answer (score 1):

In your final if statement it looks like the KEYUP events that are supposed to reset the dx/dy of Car2 are setting the dx/dy values for Car1 instead. This may be the source of your bug.

Comment: thank you I didn't notice that. I did charge it but it didn't fix the issue as its still only moving diagonally

Comment: Does Car2 still move diagonally if you only press a single arrow key? For example, if when the program started you just pressed Right Arrow, would Car2 still move diagonally?

Comment: when I press up and down it moves diagonal and when I press on the right and left it does nothing

Comment: Can you please include the code where you update the positions of the Cars using speed/dx/dy? That may be where the issue is hiding.

Comment: You are adding the value of car2dx to the value of car2y. You should instead add car2dy. Also, a convenient shorthand for car2y = car2y + car2dy is car2y += car2dy. This will do the same exact thing and is slightly more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This line has a typo:

```
        car2y = car2y + car2dx
```

It should be:

```
        car2y = car2y + car2dy
```

Note the last character is corrected to be `y` not `x`.

Though would be clearer to use the `+=` operator and write it as:

```
        car2y += car2dy
```

You also have other errors in this section:

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key in (pygame.K_w, pygame.K_s):
            car1dx = 0
        elif event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d):
            car1dy = 0

        if event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
            car1dx = 0
        elif event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
            car1dy = 0
```

You are resetting the wrong variables. You are resetting the dy instead of the dx and vise versa, and in the arrow key section you forgot to change it to car2. Like this:

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key in (pygame.K_w, pygame.K_s):
            car1dy = 0
        elif event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d):
            car1dx = 0

        elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
            car2dy = 0
        elif event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
            car2dx = 0
```

Note: in the above I also changed the second `if` to an `elif`. This will not affect the correctness of the code, it just avoids an unnecessary if check in the case where it already matched above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake here:

```
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_w, pygame.K_s):
                car1dx = 0
            elif event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d):
                car1dy = 0

            if event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
                car1dx = 0
            elif event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                car1dy = 0
```

You are using car1dx and car1dy where it should be car2dx and car2dy:

```
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_w, pygame.K_s):
                car1dx = 0
            elif event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d):
                car1dy = 0

            if event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
                car2dx = 0
            elif event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                car2dy = 0
```

Since the arrow keys are for car 2

You should also change the line:

```
car2y = car2y + car2dx
```

This should change into:

```
car2y += car2dy
```